# wrong escaping of request url by aiohttp

Tags: python, url, escaping, uri, aiohttp

aiohttp e.g:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
            async with session.get('http://p3-pc-sign.douyinpic.com/tos-cn-i-0813/dd367e76c9ea41ab9ee43b8f171e45aa~tplv-dy-aweme-images:q75.webp?x-expires=1691013600&x-signature=c52PtqjdBH%2FkUluVO79XQpC1fnw%3D&from=3213915784&s=PackSourceEnum_PUBLISH&se=false&sc=image&biz_tag=aweme_images&l=20230720060500934814BD78FB30518EED',headers={'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.31.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'close'}) as resp:
            # async with session.get('https://p9-pc-sign.douyinpic.com/tos-cn-i-0813/dd367e76c9ea41ab9ee43b8f171e45aa~tplv-dy-aweme-images:q75.webp?biz_tag=aweme_images&from=3213915784&s=PackSourceEnum_PUBLISH&sc=image&se=false&x-expires=1691013600&x-signature=Q9L9WjCpfKLRXEwxdDhaq1RgOjs%3D') as resp:
                print(resp.headers['Content-Type'])
                print(await resp.text())
asyncio.run(main())
```

requests e.g:

```
import requests
rsps=requests.get('http://p3-pc-sign.douyinpic.com/tos-cn-i-0813/dd367e76c9ea41ab9ee43b8f171e45aa~tplv-dy-aweme-images:q75.webp?x-expires=1691013600&x-signature=c52PtqjdBH%2FkUluVO79XQpC1fnw%3D&from=3213915784&s=PackSourceEnum_PUBLISH&se=false&sc=image&biz_tag=aweme_images&l=20230720060500934814BD78FB30518EED',headers={'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.31.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'close'})
print(rsps.headers['Content-Type'])
print(rsps.text)
```

packet capture analysis diff:  '/'  '%2F'

requests :

```
Request URI Query Parameter: x-signature=c52PtqjdBH%2FkUluVO79XQpC1fnw%3D
```

aiohttp :

```
Request URI Query Parameter: x-signature=c52PtqjdBH/kUluVO79XQpC1fnw%3D
```

All other request Query Parameter and headers are the same.

The example URL is fine with the requests library and the browser.
But the code with aiohttp library result in 403.

Answer (score 0):

[docs.aiohttp.org](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#passing-parameters-in-urls:%7E:text=aiohttp%20internally%20performs%20URL%20canonicalization%20before%20sending%20request.:%7E:text=aiohttp%20internally%20performs%20URL%20canonicalization%20before%20sending%20request.)

[github closed issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/7393)

Note
aiohttp internally performs URL canonicalization before sending request.

Canonicalization encodes host part by IDNA codec and applies requoting to path and query parts.

For example URL('http://example.com/путь/%30?a=%31') is converted to URL('http://example.com/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C/0?a=1').

Sometimes canonicalization is not desirable if server accepts exact representation and does not requote URL itself.

To disable canonicalization use encoded=True parameter for URL construction:

```
from yarl import URL
await session.get(
    URL('http://example.com/%30', encoded=True))
```